# skipping connection between api and ids in local validation mode

Tags: identityserver3

In a 'Local" validation mode Web Service(API) will connect to Ids server to get public key from Ids server certificate during the startup. Can public key be pre installed so that no connection is done from api to Ids at all in Local mode?

I have a situation where one of my clients wants to host Ids and only wants client devices running locally to connect to it and since api hosted by me outside of there network they do not want me to connect.

thank you
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can statically configure the issuer name and signing certificate using the `IssuerName` and `SigningCertificate` properties on the options class.

As documented here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/consuming/options.html

Comment: thank you, works great!
 feel stupid. i saw the parameters but they did not register with me ;~(